# How do I find the following x amount of characters after a keyword in PHP?

Tags: php, string, extract

I want to be able to only store the 11 characters following a certain keyword (watch?v=) in PHP, nothing after and nothing before.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: `$result = substr($str, strpos($str, $after) + strlen($after), 11);` where `$str` is your string and `$after` is the search string (`watch?v=` in this case). [See demo](https://eval.in/141340).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strpos()` to find the `watch?v=`, then use the `substr()` method to get 11 characters after.

docs for the `strpos` function:
https://www.php.net/strpos

docs for the `substr` function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Don't know why this is downvotes, this is the answer, with documentation and a basic explanation how to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP strpos() and substr() functions.

Comment: I think this is not a worthy answer, but not worth a downvote either, I canceled it out with a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($string, strpos($string, "keyword"), length);
```

In here,
 $string - url,
 "keyword" - watch?v=,
 $length - 11